# Magento EE Enterprise order emails sending duplicates and wrong recipient

Tags: magento, enterprise

Our Magento EE, I must enphasize Enterprise because I've come across a couple of solutions for this same problem but for Magento CE. Magento EE doesn't have core_email_queue_recipients table.

So our Magento is multi-sites and specifically 2 sites, one ebay and the other Amazon connected through M2EPro are having problem.

Ebay site is sending the order confirmation to the right customer as well as to another ebay customer totally unrelated which is horrible.

Amazon site is sending order confirmations to the right customers but sending twice which is not so bad but still.

It did started to happen after we connect a second ebay account under another website/store through m2epro and also our site crashed a few times around this same moment. The new ebay account has already been removed but problem continues.
M2EPro support just don't care, they say it's not related to us and period.

Our 2 other websites which are traded through the platform are fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Hey, perhaps I should post it also on magento stack exchange.Though I can only see a magento(php) programmer answering that so it's gotta be programming-related no?

Comment: No. If you had asked "What is your favourite bird?" and someone answered "Duck." it doesn't mean the question was about ducks. You need to ask a programming-related question. Show some code, state what's not working with the code, and what is should do.